# Python NLP: How do I autocorrect and tokenize a body of text only to a set list of words?

Tags: python, nlp, autocorrect

Example:

```
token_list = ['Allen Bradley', 'Haas', 'Fanuc']

input_string = 'I use Alln Brdly machins but dont no how to use Has ones.'

output_tokens = ['Allen Bradley', 'Haas']
```

Comment: How did you get the output_tokens from the input_string?

Comment: That's the question haha..

Comment: Take a look at this - https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/

Answer (score 2):

Using [textdistance](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/) could help you find the distance of two words for examply by using the hamming distance.

```
import textdistance as td

list = ['Allen', 'Bradley', 'Haas', 'Fanuc']

string = 'I use Alln Brdly machins but dont no how to use Has ones.'

#Defining a weight function to estimate the metrical distance of two words
#here the hamming similarity and distance are used
def word_correlation(word1: str, word2: str):
    sim_norm = td.hamming.normalized_similarity(word1, word2)
    dist_norm = td.hamming.normalized_distance(word1, word2)

    return {"similarity": sim_norm,
            "distance": dist_norm
            }

#splitting the sentence "string" into single words
words = [word for word in string.split(" ")]

#calculating the hamming distances and similarities for each word of the sentence
#with each of the chosen keywords contained in list
statistics = []
for i in range(len(list)):
    statistics.append({"check": list[i],
                   "with": {"words": [],
                            "cor": []
                            }
                   }
                  )
    for word in words:
        statistics[i]["with"]["words"].append(word)
        statistics[i]["with"]["cor"].append(word_correlation(word, list[i]))


#printing only the results with high similarities
result = []
for res in statistics:
    correction = res["check"]

    i = 0
    for cor in res["with"]["cor"]:
        
        #filtering of the propositional corrections by the normalized hamming
        #similarity
        if (cor["similarity"] > 0.25):
                result.append({"correction": correction,
                               "word": res["with"]["words"][i],
                               "likelyhood": cor["similarity"]
                               }
                              )

        i += 1


print(result)
```

This will return:

```
[{'correction': 'Allen', 'word': 'Alln', 'likelyhood': 0.6}, {'correction': 'Bradley', 'word': 'Brdly', 'likelyhood': 0.2857142857142857}, {'correction': 'Haas', 'word': 'Has', 'likelyhood': 0.5}]
```

You should definitely look into the definition of the metric between two words as my given solution using, e.g. the hamming distance, can give deviating results for words of different lengths! The definition should only be applied to words of the same size. [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)

As my example uses the hamming distance as the words are expected to be equal a typo will only change the length by +-1 in most cases. Therefore, the usage of the hamming distance or the hamming similarity as used in [textdistance](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/) should work in simple cases.

Comment: Nice try. The OP says he does not have a list of correct words. Where did you get it from? What will happen to your algo if you supply a corpus of all English words to your algo? What will you choose in case of draws? Don't you think the correct suggestion should depend on surrounding text (both pre- and post-) ?

Comment: Mhm if thats the case, then i am totally of. But i would argue that the identification of unkown words is kind of mathematically difficult if not impossible especially if you have no database and use no machine learning. Either you have some assumption to extract and autocorrect the words. For this you could either attach a database with known correct words. I added specifically that this is a first approach that might deviate from the expected results. To your question (pre/post): yes. Please correct me if i am wrong. Maybe i am not really helpful due to a missunderstanding on my side?

Comment: Naive correction may do with simple distance measures, but in OCR or speech recognition you'd better add sequence modelling on top to help distinguish between different candidates.

Comment: Sounds very fair. Thanks for elaborating!